# Display data from firebase with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have a typescript file with this part of code:

```
export class HomePage {

  createprofile = {} as CreateProfile;
  profileData: FirebaseObjectObservable<CreateProfile>;


  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private toast: ToastController, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  goToYourItemsListPage(){
    this.navCtrl.setRoot("YourItemsListPage");
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
      if(data && data.email && data.uid){
        this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`create-profile/${data.uid}`);
        //console.log(data);
      }else{
        this.toast.create({
          message: `Could not find authentication details!`,
          duration: 3000,
          position: "bottom"
        }).present();
      }

    });
  }

}
```

And in home.html I am adding this code:

```
<h1>Welcome, {{(profileData | async)?.firstName}}!</h1>
```

But it is not displaying error nor any value it's just: "Welcome !"

What am I missing here?

I'm a newbie to ionic.

Thank you

Comment: You can refer my repo that i make of CRUD of firebase
https://github.com/mtfaroks/ionic-firebase-crud

Comment: Thank you Mustafa, I will check it and get back to you.

Comment: Of course, My pleasure